# Rails + JS - Using instance variable (array of arrays with strings)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I have the following in a html.erb file:

```
<%= @location_list = [['test',2]] %>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var test = <%= @location_list.to_json %>
 alert(test);
</script>
```

And the alert is not showing up.

However if I do `<%= @location_list = [[3,2]] %>` - The alert is showing up.

Why?

Comment: Are there any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Kyle. Doing @location_list.to_json.html_safe did the trick, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%= %> tag means output something. In your case, you probably dont want to output anything, so I guess you are looking for 
<% @location_list = [['test',2]] %>, which means normal statement no output will be involved

Sorry, havn't really answer your question.

```
var test = <%= @location_list.to_json %>
```

should be

```
var test = "<%=j @location_list.to_json %>"
```